# How to use wifi p2p for scanning and connecting devices through different apps

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to this. 
Two different apps and i require one of them to scan and connect to the second different app with the wifi p2p in Android. So what i am trying to do is one app to look for another app and capture a specific peer( because both the apps are different).

Answer (score 0):

The process is the same if it's the same app or different apps. Just discover your peer, apply your business logic to determine if you have to connect to it and then do it.